# Substrate account abstraction

Tags: ink

I'm interested in learning about account abstraction in Substrate using Ink!. As far as I understand, smart contracts in Substrate cannot store keys or sign transactions.

However, I came across this documentation on the Polkadot Wiki: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-account-abstraction, which states: "Account abstraction can be implemented in parachains also with traditional smart-contracts for example using the ink! smart contract language."

Despite this, I haven't found any examples of such an implementation in Ink!. Does anyone have a solution or a conceptual architecture that would allow achieving similar functionality, or perhaps can point me towards resources where I could learn how to implement this myself?

Thank you!